# Foreach through different xml nodes

Tags: c#, xml, quickbooks

I have an XML response returned from QuickBooks. Here what I am trying to do is I need to update "LISTID" which is in "CustomerRet", based on the "DataExtValue" ID  in the "DataExtRet".This "DataExtValue" ID  which already exists in my database. I need to read both the values  "listId" and "dataextvalue".How do I loop through these values?

> Below is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<CustomerAddRs statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status 
OK">
<CustomerRet>
<ListID>8000002B-1502038359</ListID>
<TimeCreated>2017-08-06T22:22:39+05:30</TimeCreated>
<TimeModified>2017-08-06T22:22:39+05:30</TimeModified>
<EditSequence>1502038359</EditSequence>
<Name>MVK -C17</Name>
<FullName>MVK -C17</FullName>
<IsActive>true</IsActive>
<Sublevel>0</Sublevel>
<Balance>0.00</Balance>
<TotalBalance>0.00</TotalBalance>
<JobStatus>None</JobStatus>
<PreferredDeliveryMethod>None</PreferredDeliveryMethod>
</CustomerRet>
</CustomerAddRs>

<DataExtModRs statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status OK">
<DataExtRet>
<OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
<DataExtName>Category</DataExtName>
<DataExtType>STR255TYPE</DataExtType>
<DataExtValue>1319</DataExtValue>
</DataExtRet>
</DataExtModRs> 

<CustomerAddRs statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status 
OK">
<CustomerRet>
<ListID>8000002C-1502038359</ListID>
<TimeCreated>2017-08-06T22:22:39+05:30</TimeCreated>
<TimeModified>2017-08-06T22:22:39+05:30</TimeModified>
<EditSequence>1502038359</EditSequence>
<Name>Mutex-C17</Name>
<FullName>Mutex-C17</FullName>
<IsActive>true</IsActive>
<Sublevel>0</Sublevel>
<Balance>0.00</Balance>
<TotalBalance>0.00</TotalBalance>
<JobStatus>None</JobStatus>
<PreferredDeliveryMethod>None</PreferredDeliveryMethod>
</CustomerRet>
</CustomerAddRs>

<DataExtModRs statusCode="0" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="Status 
OK">
<DataExtRet>
<OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
<DataExtName>Category</DataExtName>
<DataExtType>STR255TYPE</DataExtType>
<DataExtValue>1524</DataExtValue>
</DataExtRet>
</DataExtModRs>
</QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>
```

> here is my c# code

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

xmlDoc.LoadXml(response);
```

XmlNodeList parentNode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("CustomerRet");
            XmlNodeList customnode = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("DataExtRet");

`foreach (XmlNode childrenNode in parentNode)
            {

                cust.CustomerListID = childrenNode.SelectSingleNode("ListID").InnerText;
               //Here I need to get the DataExtValue which is in customnode 
            }`

Comment: It's not clear how `CustomerAddRs` relates to `DataExtModRs`. Is there some element value to 'join' on, or are they related only by virtue of the fact they're siblings?

Comment: There is no actual relation among those two. While sending the request I am forming XML in such a way that "Dataextvalue" which is nothing but custom data that should be next to the related customer list item.So that in response I am getting it in the same order.

Comment: I would really glad if there is a way to send custom data inside the customer request.But this won't be possible in the API.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to XML. The query below finds the first `DataExtValue` that follows the `CustomerAddRs` element you're currently looping through.

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

foreach (var customerAddrs in doc.Descendants("CustomerAddRs"))
{
    var listId = customerAddrs
        .Elements("CustomerRet")
        .Elements("ListID")
        .Single();

    var dataExtValue = (int) customerAddrs
        .ElementsAfterSelf("DataExtModRs")
        .Descendants("DataExtValue")
        .First();

    listId.Value = $"New-ID-Based-On-{dataExtValue}";
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/64wvGN) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually multiple ways to do this. To name just two.

1. You can deserialize this XML to an object representation.  Then   it
   would be trivial to access the DataExtValue property.
   [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-deserialize-an-object)
2. You can use a
   XPath expression on the parentnode to get the value of DataExtValue.
   [Xpath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(file);

foreach (var trans in xDocument.Descendants("QBXMLMsgsRs"))
{    
    var val1 =
        (string)trans.Descendants("CustomerRet").Elements("ListID")
        .First();
    var val2 =  
        (string)trans.Descendants("DataExtRet").Elements("DataExtValue")
        .First();
}
```

Comment: I am trying to read the XML through the string.when I try through your code I am getting an error as "Invalid characters in the path".

Comment: @satepuritarun I suspect you're passing the XML string to `Load` rather than the path to the file. If that's the case, you want `XDocument.Parse` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that.But it is not looping through all the elements.It is returning values only for the first customer.